# Killing a single service when multiple services are under same pid using taskkill

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-command-prompt

I am trying to kill wuauserv on a windows server 2008 R2, however it has the same PID as other services which I don't want to kill. I assume running taskkill /f /pid [PID] would kill them all, how do I target just the wuauserv service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that with taskkill.

Find the PID of the svchost.exe process the service runs in:

```
tasklist /FI "SERVICES eq wuauserv"
```

Then use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and double click on that process and change to the `Threads` tab, kill the four threads associated with the wuauserv service.

This will leave the process in a un-stable state, but I guess if you couldn't stop it normally, it was unstable already.

Unstable means, the service control manager still thinks it is running and can not stop it.